# How to get count of list datum in Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-recyclerview

In my application I should get **list** from server and show into `RecyclerView`. 
I want the **number of winners** show `recyclerView` item.
**My List from server :**

```
    "title": "Transporter",
      "awards": [
        {
          "description": "Best Performance by an Actor in a Motion Picture - Comedy or Musical",
          "year": 1998,
          "won": false,
          "id": 13769,
          "name": "Jackie Brown",
          "entityType": 1,
          "imageUrl": "example.com/thumb2-13769 Jackie Brown.jpg"
        },
        {
          "description": "Best Performance by an Actor in a Supporting Role in a Motion Picture",
          "year": 1997,
          "won": false,
          "id": 1353,
          "name": "A Time to Kill",
          "entityType": 1,
          "imageUrl": "http://example.com/thumb2-1353 A Time to Kill.jpg"
        },
        {
          "description": "Best Performance by an Actor in a Miniseries or Motion Picture Made for Television",
          "year": 1995,
          "won": true,
          "id": 86836,
          "name": "Against the Wall",
          "entityType": 1,
          "imageUrl": "http://example.com/thumb2-86836 Against the Wall 1994.jpg"
        },
        {
          "description": "Best Performance by an Actor in a Supporting Role in a Motion Picture",
          "year": 1995,
          "won": false,
          "id": 1378,
          "name": "Pulp Fiction",
          "entityType": 1,
          "imageUrl": "http://example.com/thumb2-1378 Pulp Fiction.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For connect to server I use `Retrofit` and **my code :**

```
InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
    Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call = api.getCelebrityAward(celebrityAwardSendData);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<CelebrityAwardResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call, Response<CelebrityAwardResponse> response) {
            if (response.body().getData() != null) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

How can I know how many data **"won": true** ?

please help me, Thanks all <3

Comment: post your CelebrityAwardResponse class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `JSONArray` object from your string response data, then iterate it and take the tally:

```
int totalWins = 0;
String data = response.body().getData();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
    boolean won = row.getBoolean("won");
    totalWins += won ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I assume you would be handling this in your `onResponse()` method, though the above code should be valid anywhere in your activity where you have a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

```
InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call = api.getCelebrityAward(celebrityAwardSendData);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CelebrityAwardResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call, Response<CelebrityAwardResponse> response) {
                if (response.body().getData() != null) {
                    try {
                        String data = response.body();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("awards");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            boolean won = row.getBoolean("won");
                            if (won) {
                                Log.d("won", "won name : " + row.getString("name"));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<CelebrityAwardResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });
```

i hope it's useful to you ...!

Comment: can you send me you skype ID? please

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to create RecylerView in Android

```
 public Adaptername  adapterobj;

         adapterobj = new Adapter name(context, ArrayList);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                    recyclerViewOrders.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerViewOrders.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerViewOrders.setAdapter(adapterobj );
                    recyclerViewOrders.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                    adapterobj .notify
               DataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try {
                                int wins = 0;
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().getData());
                                JSONArray awards = jsonObject.getJSONArray("awards");
                                for(int i=0;i<awards.length();i++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject award = awards.getJSONObject(i);
                                    if(award.getBoolean("won"))
                                        wins++;
                                }
                                System.out.println(wins);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```